# PriorityQueue incl. .poll() and Compareable explanation? (Java)

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am currently stuck at the following problem:

I have a class "WaitingRoom" and "Patient". Patients with the status "emergency" are the first ones in the queue (PriorityQueue waitingRoom) (time does not matter) and the others are sorted by their appointment.

I am testing my program with the following code:

```
    WaitingRoom wz = new WaitingRoom();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
    c.set(2009, Calendar.OCTOBER, 21, 9, 35);
    wz.comesIn(new Patient("Smith Jones", c.getTime(), false));
    c.set(2009, Calendar.OCTOBER, 21, 9, 30);
    wz.comesIn(new Patient("Mueller Johan", c.getTime(), false));
    wz.comesIn(new Patient("Emergency Brooklyn", new Date(), true));
    c.set(2009, Calendar.OCTOBER, 21, 8, 30);
    wz.comesIn(new Patient("Richard Smith", c.getTime(), false));
    c.set(2009, Calendar.OCTOBER, 21, 9, 31);
    wz.comesIn(new Patient("Kimberly Adams", c.getTime(), false));
    c.set(2009, Calendar.OCTOBER, 21, 9, 29);
    wz.comesIn(new Patient("Random Name", c.getTime(), false));
    Patient patient = wz.getNextPatient();
    assertEquals("Emergency Brooklyn", patient.getName());
    patient = wz.getNextPatient();
    assertEquals("Richard Smith", patient.getName());
    patient = wz.getNextPatient();
    assertEquals("Random Name", patient.getName());
```

The method `.getNextPatient()` returns `waitingRoom.poll();`
And my compareTo:

```
public int compareTo(Patient other) {
    if (other.emergency) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        if (this.emergency) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return this.appointment.compareTo(other.appointment);
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine. But I do not understand how the sorting works. I tried understanding it by using the debugger.. but I still don't get it. It sorts it when a next patient comes in (how does it choose the other patient?) and another time when I use the function `.poll()`.

Could you please explain me how it works?

Thank you advance!

Comment: It works by accident. Your comparator doesn't respect the contract of compareTo: if patients A and B are both in an emergency, the A.compareTo(B) returns 1 (so A is greater than B), but B.compareTo(A) also returns 1 (so now B is greater than A). It should compare by appointment if both are in an emergency. That said, I don't understand your question. It works because a PriorityQueue uses the comparator to return the patients in the order defined by the comparator. That's the contract of the class. How it does that is interesting (it uses a heap), but irrelevant. Look at the source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that the actual first patient (no emergency) is added at the end (see the test)... and the compareTo only compares two values and does not iterate over all patients to check their appointment to add the patient at the correct position and this is what confuses me.

Comment: A PriorityQueue doesn't use a list to store its elements. It uses a heap. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29. The reason is precisely that it is faster than using a list, because less comparisons are needed to insert the element in the queue.

Comment: Explains a lot now... thank you very much!

Comment: Source code at [JDK Repo](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/ad33c27c9f15/src/share/classes/java/util/PriorityQueue.java).